# Admin to see Quantity change history of a product

Tags: quantity, history

Is there a way to show quantity change history by product in admin interface?

This is a very useful feature and is available in WMS solutions. We used in Solid Commerce for example, was very helpful.
I searched extensions but couldn't find something similar.

Any idea of something or custom code?

[image]

1.8.1
Tnx

Comment: Have you checked this extension? https://github.com/firegento/firegento-adminmonitoring

Answer (score 2):

There is a free extension by Johann Reinke, which does exactly that. You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/jreinke/magento-stock-movements). A full explanation can be found on [bubblecode.net](http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/02/07/magento-save-product-stock-moves/). The screenshot shows what it does:

[image: Jreinke Stock Movements]

I did not use it yet, but it looks quite promising.

Comment: Great plugin! Very useful for diagnosing product inventory bugs. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not keep track of inventory adjustments. So, it will be a custom implementation.

On the Enterprise version, there is an admin log, but this will be understandably limited to admin changes.